# g++ static library depends on dynamic libraries

Tags: c++, c, build, mingw, gnu-make

I have some static library. for example libpuchuu.a
it depends on dynamic library. for example libSDL.so
(but of cource I have libSDL.a)
Creation of libpuchuu.a is simple:

```
ar -rcs object_file_1.o object_file_2.o
```

But I can't link my project with libpuchuu.a!
undefined references attack my console!

At some forum I have found such sentence:
all dependences of static library is in this library
if your object files depends on y.a you must unpack(ar) y.a object files
    to your folder, then pack all objects to your new library. Questions:

1. is it true?
2. if it is true:
   object file puchuu.o depends on libSDL.a
   how to make libpuchuu.a?
3. another solution?

PS

I have made a simple example and posted it to pastebin:

http://paste.lisp.org/display/115456

building commands:

```
g++ -O3 -c index.cpp -I/usr/local/include/SDL
g++ -O3 -c lib.cpp -I/usr/local/include/SDL
ar rv libpuchuu.a lib.o
g++ -O3 -o program.exe index.o -L/usr/local/lib -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL -mwindows -lSDL_image -L. -lpuchuu
```

...
undefined references from index.cpp!

Comment: You should elaborate what undefined references arise. That may lead to the shared object missing.

Comment: Could you please include that as text rather than as an image?

Comment: Oh, man, there is a Russian warning there regarding sdldraw!! (that ought to be bad!) :)

Comment: I don't think I can open 7z files.

Comment: yes i am from belarus. but all money is in us. we should try write and speak english! ^_w_^

Comment: Show the exact error message, and show the command that's run when you do the linking.

Comment: @puchu - I edited your question and pasted your code to pastebin so it will stay forever.  One goal of this site is to educate others.  So all details required to answer a question should be available forever.  Also, I went through significantly more effort than the average question answerer here would've.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding `-lSDL` to the command line of your linker?

The undefined references are to symbols you are trying to define in `lib.cpp` which you use `ar` to package up in `libpuchuu.a`.  Unfortunately, you aren't defining the symbols you think you're defining.  `using namespace sdl;` does not automagically cause everything you define to be in the `sdl` namespace.  All it does is arrange it so that when the compiler looks for a particular name it looks for it in the `sdl` namespace along with the main namespace.

You need to wrap the functions defined in `lib.cpp` with `namespace sdl { .... functions ... }` and your code will link just fine.

In my experience, when I make a mistake with something unfamiliar, the mistake is usually a really dumb one that has nothing to do with the thing I'm unfamiliar with.  But because I'm working in unknown territory I automatically assume that my lack of knowledge of the territory must be at fault, not that I did something stupid.

You might find that experience of mine applicable.

And, as a side note, the idea of 'undefined references attacking your console' is rather amusingly bizarre, and leaves me with an image of your screen and keyboard left in a smoking ruin after you try to link.

Comment: of cource. but undefined references attack!

Comment: @puchu - Adding `-lSDL` should've solved your problem.  If you provide more detail about the exact commands you're running, perhaps the actual problem will be uncovered, cowering in its hiding place.

Comment: >>undefined references are to symbols you define in lib.cpp. as you see answer is how to fix it. just write...